# Mono xbuild error on windows

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono

I need use xbuild command to build csproj to one file[test.il].

error message is [MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified].

what mean about this error message?
and how to solve?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=c:\MinGw\bin;c:\mono-3.2.3\bin;%PATH%
SET DMCS="C:\mono-3.2.3\lib\mono\4.5\xbuild.exe"
mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 %DMCS% -unsafe+ -o+ -sdk:4.5 -target:exe -out:test.il  H:\Csharp\Mono\Test\TestBuild\TestBuild\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj
```

Comment: The code seems to be modified from a file that uses dmcs command. The command for xbuild usually is different. Pleas check xbuild man page.

Answer (score 3):

> mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 %DMCS% -unsafe+ -o+ -sdk:4.5 -target:exe -out:test.il  H:\Csharp\Mono\Test\TestBuild\TestBuild\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj

This command is mixing up invocation of `xbuild` with `*mcs`. The arguments that you are passing to the exe like `-unsafe+ -o+ -sdk:4.5 -target:exe -out:test.il` are meant for `mcs` and not xbuild. Just use `xbuild.bat` script (probably in `C:\mono-3.2.3\bin\xbuild.bat`) or change what you have to:

`mono C:\mono-3.2.3\lib\mono\4.5\xbuild.exe H:\Csharp\Mono\Test\TestBuild\TestBuild\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj`

Answer (score 1):

Running `xbuild` without using the installed `xbuild` shell script:

```
mono $MONO_OPTIONS C:\mono-3.2.3\lib\mono\4.5\xbuild.exe yourproject.csproj
```